# AngularJS: global search of Smart Table does not work with data loaded asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm using [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) for AngularJS but  global search of Smart Table does not work with data loaded asynchronously. I made this little [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Xa4nIKhcvKy7Purjaw0?p=preview) to see the problem in action.

*Further details:*

Accordingly to the doc, there are two copies of data, one is for the rendering while the other is the "static" safe copy of data. I have a table that displays data loaded via API. Here there is the table declaration in my HTML:

```
<table st-table="stc.displayedCollection" st-safe-src="stc.rowList" class="table table-striped">
```

As you can see, I'm telling smart table "who" are the two copies of my data.

Here there is the piece of controller to fetch data:

```
 stc.fetchData = function(val) {
      console.log(val);
      $http.get('data'+val+'.json').success(function(data){
          stc.rowList = data;
          stc.displayedCollection = [].concat(stc.rowList);
      });
  };
```

Once data are loaded, my smart table does not work fine (e.g. filter and sorting don't work).

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i already had the same problem!!

you need to repeat the displayed collection instead the safe

```
 <table st-table="stc.displayedCollection" st-safe-src="stc.rowList>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in stc.displayedCollection">
```

Comment: Perfect, It works! I updated the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FXCMUy6nmMwFDCyliLLx?p=preview)

Comment: Refer this links http://plnkr.co/edit/FZHYcr?p=preview  and https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/144#issuecomment-53828951